# Getting validation error inside input type file using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am facing an issue while selecting file using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```html
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.compregdoc.$touched && billdata.compregdoc.$invalid }">
  <input type="file" 
         class="filestyle form-control" 
         data-size="lg" 
         name="compregdoc" 
         id="compregdoc" 
         ng-model="compregfile" 
         ngf-pattern="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
         accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" 
         ngf-select="onCompRegFileSelect($file);" 
         ngf-max-size="2MB">

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" 
     ng-messages="billdata.compregdoc.$error" 
     ng-if="billdata.compregdoc.$touched">

  <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field only accepts .pdf,.ppt,.docx files.</p>
  <p ng-message="maxSize" style="color:#F00;">File is too large.Max size is 2 mb.</p>
</div>
```

In this case I am only able to upload `pdf` type file. But here I need `pdf,ppt,docx,excel` format file upload. When I am selecting the docx file it is showing me the validation message that `This field only accepts .pdf,.ppt,.docx files`.

Comment: The file that you are selecting has a mime type that is none of the ones that you have specified in the ngf-pattern.

Comment: Alternatively you can use .pdf,.ppt,... format for ngf-pattern instead of the mime types which would only validate the file's extension.

Comment: @danial I am using version 7.0.15 and it does not filter by .ris files when i specify `ngf-pattern=".ris"`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @danial Sorry, I should have updated this...the following combo is what did it for me: `ngf-pattern="'.ris'"` and `accept=".ris"`. Both were needed.